# Group tag values by sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to manipulate an XML using jQuery. In particular, I'd like to group the values of the `Question` tags by `GroupName` so I can create a jQuery Accordion with the `GroupName` as header and the questions per `GroupName` as content.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GenericFormData>
  <UserQuestions>
    <UserQuestion>
      <BoxID>Box_1_6</BoxID>
      <Question>Refund requested?</Question>
      <FieldType>3</FieldType>
      <GroupName/>
    </UserQuestion>
    <UserQuestion>
      <BoxID>Box_1_7</BoxID>
      <Question>Would you like to receive forms?</Question>
      <FieldType>3</FieldType>
      <GroupName/>
    </UserQuestion>
    <UserQuestion>
      <BoxID>Box_2_14</BoxID>
      <Question>Listing nihil?</Question>
      <FieldType>3</FieldType>
      <GroupName>VIII</GroupName>
    </UserQuestion>
    <UserQuestion>
      <BoxID>Box_2_15</BoxID>
      <Question>Creation date</Question>
      <FieldType>2</FieldType>
      <GroupName>Date and signature</GroupName>
    </UserQuestion>
    <UserQuestion>
      <BoxID>Box_2_16</BoxID>
      <Question>Name of the person signing</Question>
      <FieldType>0</FieldType>
      <GroupName>Date and signature</GroupName>
    </UserQuestion>
    <UserQuestion>
      <BoxID>Box_2_17</BoxID>
      <Question>function of the person signing</Question>
      <FieldType>0</FieldType>
      <GroupName>Date and signature</GroupName>
    </UserQuestion>
    <UserQuestion>
      <BoxID>Box_2_18</BoxID>
      <Question>Phone number of the person signing</Question>
      <FieldType>0</FieldType>
      <GroupName>Date and signature</GroupName>
    </UserQuestion>
    <UserQuestion>
      <BoxID>Box99</BoxID>
      <Question>Liability</Question>
      <FieldType>1</FieldType>
      <GroupName>VII</GroupName>
    </UserQuestion>
  </UserQuestions>
</GenericFormData>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(xmlDoc).find('GroupName').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === groupnames[i].toString();
}).parents().find('UserQuestion').each(function () {
    //logic to display `Question` goes here
});
```

but that doesn't work like it should. I'm iterating over `groupnames` (contains the unique values as it should) but the `each()` method yields way too much. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

If I understand correctly; I think your mistake lies in the 3rd line

> ```
> }).parents().find('UserQuestion').each(function () {
>          ^----------------------^
> ```

Currently you're selecting all of the `parents()` , which fundamentally will

> Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

This means that by selecting the parents, you're going to get higher elements than `UserQuestion`, which will deem your previous filtering redundant.

### Solution

If you're able to determine that `groupName` will be an immediate child, then you can instead use `parent()`, dropping the plural. Alternatively, if this isn't a guarantee, you can can try adding a selector to your current statement, to only select `UserQuestion`s, like so:

```
$(xmlDoc).find('GroupName').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === groupnames[i].toString();
}).parents('UserQuestion').each(function () {
    //logic to display `Question` goes here
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I also understand why this works and my solution didn't. Thanks a lot.